# Blender for online human-movement visualization

Tags: python, inverse-kinematics, makehuman, motion-capture

I would like to know if I can use Blender to visualize human motion in an online manner.
In my setup, I will have motion capture system which will provide the position of some arbitrary marker (attached to a human subjects).
My goal is to use these marker position (given that I know where they are placed on the human subject) and use IK and visualize the human model on the screen.

I know that in Blender, we can import human models (made by MakeHuman) and play around with FK and IK.

My question: is it possible to run Blender continuously (for visualizing purposes) and use python script to send IK constraints (continuously) to the human model?

I know Blender/python allows for Socket communication. This way I can pass the position of the markers from motion capture to Blender. But I don't know (if possible), how I can set IK constraints.
I would appreciate it a lot if you guys could share with me some simple examples.